# How can I remove these "devices" on the root of my Macbook Air?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-yosemite

Deleting (cmd+delete) doesn't work. Right click shows an "Eject" option which also does not work.

I have Chrome on the Dev channel.

They are all empty despite the Size column informing they aren't.

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer removes the items.